# How to make foundry compile only contracts that are necessary

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I want to deploy a couple of contracts with foundry, but their versions differ. I have one script to deploy those with the first version and another to deploy those with the second. But when I run `forge script /path/to/script.sol:Contract --broadcast` it fails as it tries to compile everything in all libraries which have different versions. How to deal with this?